# Rewrite a string in php with adding information inside

Tags: php, arrays, string, url-rewriting

I have this string

```
[ 1, 6], [ 2, 5]
```

All I need is to rewrite it to be looking like

```
['lat' => 1, 'long' => 6],['lat' => 2, 'long' => 5]
```

So meaby the logic should be before every 1st number should be added 'lat' =>  and before every 2nd number 'long' => but I am not sure.
I am using php but if I have the code with the logic it would not be a problem to use any other language. Thatk you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function transform($str) {
    $str = str_replace('], ', '@', $str);
    $str = str_replace('[', "['lat' =>", $str);
    $str = str_replace(',', ", 'long' =>", $str);
    $str = str_replace('@', '],', $str);

    return $str;
}
$in  = '[ 1, 6], [ 2, 5]';
$out = "['lat' => 1, 'long' => 6],['lat' => 2, 'long' => 5]";
print assert($out == transform($in));
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to regular expressions are normal string functions:

```
<?php
$input = '[ 1, 6], [ 2, 5]';
list($latA, $longA, $latB, $longB) = sscanf($input, '[ %d, %d], [ %d, %d]');
$output = sprintf(
    "['lat' => %d, 'long' => %d],['lat' => %d, 'long' => %d]", 
    $latA, $longA, $latB, $longB
);
var_dump($output);
```

The output is:

```
string(51) "['lat' => 1, 'long' => 6],['lat' => 2, 'long' => 5]"
```

However I doubt that this *really* is what you are looking for. Both formats look more like they are not actually meant as strings, but as an array holding two numerical arrays with two elements each as input and an associative array as output. If so, then the answer would be much more simple :-)